# Python Tkinter label printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, tkinter

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk

cmd = 'curl https://ipinfo.io/ip'
puip = str(os.system(cmd))

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
label = Label(root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED)

p = str(puip)
s = p
print(type(p))

var.set(s)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I want to print the public IP of our network. Also I want to print using tkinter label. I am able to print a string, but I can't print the public IP. Output is getting the terminal, but I would like to print through label

Comment: Try this: `from subprocess import check_output` and then `puip = check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode()`

Comment: Super Thank you for your valuable information